# Need of information_schema when having sys.objects and sys.columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

What is the need for `information_schema` catalog views as they provide details which is same as (sys.objects and sys.columns).

```
information_schema.tables----->retrives from sys.objects.
information_schema.column----->retrives from sys.columns.
```

Answer (score 4):

information_schema... are ANSI compatible views, other RDBMS systems also have these views, like MySQL, postgreSQL, SQLite . `sys.columns` only exist in SQL Server

PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/information-schema.html

MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html

SQLite : http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=InformationSchema

Oracle on the other hand does NOT have these views but their own versions like `ALL_TABLES` and `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`

Comment: Please do you think you could take a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40197865/mssql-is-there-any-performance-penalty-for-wrapping-a-select-query-in-a-transa

Comment: SQLite does not have information_schema in 2019. It's very likely it wasn't available back in 2013 also.